# Delete Unrecognised Primary Partition

Tags: partitioning, filesystems

I have a TamilNadu Government laptop Lenovo B460e. First when I got it, it  had dual boot (grub) for Windows 7 and Linux .The harddisk size is 320GB. I deleted those OS and installed new Windows 7  because of some problems. It's working fine.

From the start I was able to use only two partitions System (c:) and Logical(d:). Now when I checked my diskmanagement I have 3 partitions. It had a 3rd  partition without any name or letter or type. It had nearly 95GB free space. Its status says *"Healthy(primary Partition)"*.

When I try to delete the partition, it says *"This partition is not created by Windows. Do you really want to delete?"*. I definitely need some extra GB because my drives are already full. Would I be able to use that 95GB if I delete that partition and will it lead to any problems?

Answer (score 1):

The third partition is clearly a left-over from the Linux install on your system. Windows is warning you, but simply to say: Are you sure this partition is not needed elsewhere?

You may safely format it to whatever you wish, FAT or NTFS. Il will appear as drive E: on your Windows system. If you wish, you could also use the same free space to enlarge one of the existing partitions, but that cannot be done with your system on: you will have to use the installation CD, boot from that, and then you can enlarge an existing partition to encompass what appears now as the unused partition. The choice is all yours.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.My Laptop does not have a cd drive . Can It be done via a pendrive.

Comment: Actually I dont need to enlarge an existing partition. I simply need that free space.If i simply click delete will the E: appear ? I just need the simplest way possible .

Comment: Just format it to NTFS.

Comment: @user147096 No, it will not appear if you just delete it. You must first delete, then format it to NTFS. Only then will a E: drive appear in Windows.

Comment: Thanks ..It worked nice.Now I can enjoy using my extra 95GB.